# Is there any way to edit snippets and templates outside the MODx?

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

Is there any solution to make snippets, templates and maybe resources of MODx site available to edit with external editor? Besides [this hack](http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php/topic,40053.msg241935.html#msg241935) which make site less "native".

Thanks!

Comment: I hear ya, I like to use notepad++ and have a series of files on my hard drive that I edit and then paste into snippets/chunks etc. 
I'm sure this is possible to do, but doesn't look like anyone spent the time on this... yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are basically editing the contents of a database any method of editing will not be native.

If you want to edit them in a separate editor to get nice syntax highlighting then [Edit Area](http://modxcms.com/extras/package/514) is a nice plugin.

Comment: I need not only highlighting (thanks for your link, it can be really useful for me), but code hinting, errors highlighting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the question is rather old, you can check any resource, snippet or chunk to be "**static**". So it will be stored in the filesystem. You can then access and edit it via FTP and use any editor you like.